# Python: My csv.reader imports csv file as text

Tags: python, csv, import

After importing `CSV` file, the output appears like `[['1', '2', '3']]`. How can I make sure it is imported as a number?

Comment: Would be illuminating to see the input data and **code** that reproduces this rather than just your result and nothing else

Comment: `int(your_list[0][0])`

Comment: Thx EdChum. The test file is simple csv file with 3*3 matrix of integer numbers. here is the code: tst=open('test.csv')
l= []

for line in csv.reader(tst.readlines()[0:]):
    l.extend(line)

print(tst.read())
print(l)

Comment: Would you please update question with your code and sample lines in your csv file

Answer (score 3):

With the csv module `reader` function a row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings. If you want unquoted numbers not to be returned as strings use the `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` option. However, be aware that this option will convert to float. If you want to process or display these numbers as `int`s then you will have to cast them as `int`.

This is your csv file:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Assuming you want a list of lists output:

```
import csv                                                                                                                                    
tst = open('test.csv')                                                                                                                          
l = []                                                                                                                                          
reader = csv.reader(tst, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)                                                                                         
for line in reader:                                                                                                                           
    l.append(line)

print l
```

Yields:

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]]
```

To output integers, you might as well convert the strings to integers directly:

```
l = []                                                                                                                                          
tst = open('test.csv')                                                                                                                          
reader = csv.reader(tst)                                                                                                                      
for line in reader:                                                                                                                           
    l.append([int(i) for i in line])                                                                                                          

print l
```

Yields:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```